# JavaScript function returns 'illegal return statement'

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm trying to find which radio inputs are selected so I can pass the info to my main.js (Electron).

```
function checkType(){
    const types = document.getElementById('type').children;
        for (var i; i < types.length; i++){
            if (types[i].checked == true){
                return types[i].id;
            }
        }
}
```

It should return the ID of the input selected, but instead I receive an illegal return error.

Here is my div:

```
<div id="type">
    <label for="urgent">Urgent</label>
    <input type="radio" id="urgent" name="type">
    <br>
    <label for="request">Request</label>
    <input type="radio" id="request" name="type">
    <br>
    <label for="question">Question</label>
    <input type="radio" id="Question" name="type">
    <br>
</div
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Not really anything. This is the function I got after 30 minutes of trial and error.

Comment: How are you using this `checkType` function?

Comment: @GoshDarn Asking a question on Stack Overflow should NEVER be your first line of defense. You should always attempt to put effort into fixing it yourself before asking for help on Stack Overflow. Otherwise it makes it look like you just want us to do your work for you, wish is not what we are here for.

Comment: Can you post the actual error, like exactly as it looks?

Comment: I would think that you would be wanting to initialise `var i=0` - otherwise i will be an undefined type, unable to be incremented

Comment: @CharlieFish I mean, he did say he spent 30 minutes to come up with this. That's a reasonable effort.

Comment: @Feathercrown If you put in 30 minutes of effort and you answer the question “what have you tried so far” with “Not really anything”, then you didn’t put in enough effort.

Comment: @CharlieFish I could respond but I suggest we stop; comments are not for discussion.

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkType(){
    const types = document.getElementById('type').children;
    let selected;
        for (var i; i < types.length; i++){
            if (types[i].checked == true){
                selected = types[i].id
                break;
            }
        }
    return selected;
}
```

Comment: I'm using radio inputs, so only one option will be selected at any point in time.